# Низкая скорость по wifi с телефона при отсутствии подключенных по wifi ноутбуков

Tags: wifi, openwrt, tp-link

При отсутствии подключенных ноутбуков по wifi к домашнему роутеру tp-link wr842nd с прошивкой OpenWrt Chaos Calmer 15.05.1 скорость интернета на телефоне падает до 1-2mbit/sec. Как только подключаю ноутбук по wifi скорость на телефоне поднимается до 30mbit/s down и 50mbit/s up при тестировании speedtest.net и 2ip.ru.

При подключении ноутбука уровень сигнала на телефоне остается неизменным и составляет порядка -40dBm при уровне шума -95dBm. Телефон xiaomi redmi note 3 pro, аналогичная проблема наблюдается и при тестировании на более старом телефоне LG. Буду рад услышать любые идеи куда копать и в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: попробуй обновиться до 18

Comment: не слишком радужная перспектива снова вспоминать и настраивать с нуля. Хватает как простых правил/настроек, так и дополнительных пакетов и их настроек. Хотелось бы понять почему возникает данная ситуация.